# How does customized executable generation work?

Tags: copy-protection

One of the things that Valve's Steam distribution platform is known for is its Custom Executable Generation system, which creates a unique copy of a program for each person that buys it.

I'm sure that Valve isn't the only company or person to have implemented or thought of implementing such a system, however. If I wanted to try and roll my own system that generated executable files on the server side that are unique to the downloader or their account, what would I need to know how to do? What are the basics of such a system in the first place?

Answer (score 4):

For purposes of discussion, I am assuming that your program is written in C, compiled on unix, and that there is a small amount of customization done (only changing compile time constants). We start with a template, lets call it `customer.c.templ`

```
#include "customer.h"
const char custname="$$custname$$";
const int custnum=$$custnum$$;
.
.
.
```

and we write a simple script to do substitutions, say `markup.pl`

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -p
s/\$\$([^$])\$\$/$ENV[$1]/e;
```

and have our sales guys give us some customer data

```
custname="Billy Bob's Clam Shack"
custnum=404
.
.
.
```

and a simple little script:

```
#!/bin/sh
. customer_data
markup.pl <customer.c.tmpl >customer.c
make customer.o
make a.out
mv a.out $custnum.exe
```

and there you go. custom binary.

Comment: That's not too far off from my intended use case, actually. Written in C++, though, not C.

Comment: You might want to watch out, the string constants (especially) get funky when you start replacing them and misaligning data.  Padding the data of a struct out to the appropriate size and replacing the entire thing once identified may be safer.

Comment: @michaelT +1  long time ago I came across a antivirus program that put a CRC into a 'special' unused part of DOS .exe files. Can't remember the details and don't know if it will work in a modern OS but it might be a better approach than recompiling the app (and presumably the installer) for every customer.

Answer (score 0):

Often you can implement the same functionality in lightly different ways.

Thts assume you have **n** functions for each you have have **2** different implementations (which are not to be the same assembly after compiling), than you can create 
**2ⁿ** versions of your executable with the same functionality.

You can vary this aproach by changing the order of independent assembly commands, using more than 2 vaiands to choose between ...